# Vector iterator is not dereferencable, while try to read from file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

I'm writing data (structure) into file using vector, and when I attempt to retrieve data using vector iterator and it gives me: `"Vector iterator is not dereferenceable."`

This is my code:

```
void CProgram_1_STLDlg::OnBnClickedBtnView()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CFile file;
    CFileException e;
    studentVector::iterator sit;
    studentVector::iterator sBegin = sVector.begin();
    studentVector::iterator sEnd = sVector.end();

    CString path = _T("D:\\Student.txt");

    if ( file.Open(path, CFile::modeRead, &e) ) {
        while ( file.Read( (char *)&sVector, sizeof(sVector)) ) {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("File opened in read mode."), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            AfxMessageBox(_T("ID:\t")+sit->id+L"\nName:\t"
                           +sit->name+L"\nMarks:\t"+sit->marks+L
                          "\nPercentage:\t"+sit->per+L"\nState:\t"+sit->state);
            sit++;
        }
        //file.Read( (char *)&sData, sizeof(sData));

        /*for ( sIterator = sVector.begin(); sIterator != sVector.end(); sIterator++ ) {
                //AfxMessageBox(_T("ID:\t")+sIterator->id+L
                                "\nName:\t"+sIterator->name+L"\nMarks:\t"
                                +sIterator->marks+L"\nPercentage:\t"+sIterator->per+L
                               "\nState:\t"+sIterator->state);
                //AfxMessageBox(_T("Hello..Testing...!"));
        }
*/

    } else {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error! Unable to open file."), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

Now I  don't know how to resolve this error.

Note: Some of links I refer which google gave me, but I couldn't able to solve my problem.

Comment: @SHR i did that too, but one thing i'm wondering is that how program will know that there is end of file, that's why i used while loop to read file, and taking its content into vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot simply overwrite the memory of a vector. That is pretty much guaranteed to corrupt your process.

Furthermore, you never assign anything to `sit` and yet expect it to contain something sensible.

You need to parse the data in Student.txt and use vector's member functions to fill it with sensible data. The assignment will probably tell you what the file looks like so that you can parse it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple vector like

```
vector<char> cvec
```

could be overwritten
so something like

```
vector<char> cvec;
cvec.resize(100);
for(char i=0;i<100;i++)
    cvec[i]=i;
```

will work.

If you resize to correct size. Otherwise you will corrupt memory

sizeof(sVector) will deliver the size of the vector class.
this is not related to the data since data inside the vector class is nothing more than a pointer.
example:

```
class simpleVector;
{
     public:
     simpleVector(unigned int size)
     {
         p=new int[size];
     }
     int* p;
}
func()
{
    simpleVector v1(10);
    simpleVector v2(100000);
    printf("size v1= %d, Size v2= %d", sizeof(v1),sizeog(v2));
}
```

I have not checked, what sizeof will deliver for this class, but it definitely will be constant. Independent from the size that is given to constructor

An Iterator is an accessor to the Vector
but it needs to be initialized.
In the code above sit is not assigned to something. So you are not able to access something valid.

from the code line

> AfxMessageBox(_T("ID:\t")+sit->id+L"\nName:\t"+sit->name+L"\nMarks:\t"+sit->marks+L"\nPercentage:\t"+sit->per+L"\nState:\t"+sit->state);

I see the vector shall contain a complex data type build from several strings.
 so a vector element probably looks like

```
class student
{
     std::string id;
     std::string name;
     std::string marks;
     std::string per;
     std::string state;  
};
```

this is in minimum the information hold by each vector element.
usually strings have the property to have different length.
While id might be always of same length name probably don't.
Since it is not fixed length
even

```
 file.Read( (char *)&sVector, sizeof(student))
```

would not work.
so I would suggest to add a reader to the 'Student' Class:

```
class student
{
     std::string id;
     std::string name;
     std::string marks;
     std::string per;
     std::string state;  
     bool ReadElemFromFile(CFile& file)
     {
           id=ReadStringFromFile(file);
           name=ReadStringFromFile(file);
           marks=ReadStringFromFile(file);
           per=ReadStringFromFile(file);
           state=ReadStringFromFile(file);  
           if(id.empty()||name.empty()||marks.empty()||per.empty()||state.empty())
               return false;
           return true;
     }
     std::string ReadStringFromFile(CFile% file)
     {
           char c;
           std::string s;
           do
           {
                 file.read(&c,1);
                 s+=c; 
           }
           while(c!='\0')
           return s; 
     }
};
```

I know reading that way is not the most performant way to do it, but it shows,that the string terminator stored to file indicates the length of each string

now back to your code

```
void CProgram_1_STLDlg::OnBnClickedBtnView()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CFile file;
    CFileException e;
    student* sit=new Student;
    studentVector.clear();

    CString path = _T("D:\\Student.txt");

    if ( file.Open(path, CFile::modeRead, &e) ) {
        while ( sit->ReadElemFromFile(CFile& file)) {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("File opened in read mode."), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            AfxMessageBox(_T("ID:\t")+sit->id+L"\nName:\t"+sit->name+L"\nMarks:\t"+sit->marks+L"\nPercentage:\t"+sit->per+L"\nState:\t"+sit->state);
             studentVector.push_back(*sit);
        }
    } else {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error! Unable to open file."), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    delete stud;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...*"attempt to retrieve data using vector iterator and it gives me Vector iterator is not dereferenceable"*...

[Iterators](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/%7Eriesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterators.html) are pointer-like objects, however unlike raw pointers, they prevent dereferencing (accessing of the value they point to) if they are *"dangling"*.

In your case iterator `sit` is not initialized, not as, for example iterator `sBegin = sVector.begin();`, that is assigned to point to the beginning of the vector `sVector`.

Thus when you try to access an iterator that does not point to a valid value, you get an error.

In addition to that, to store an element to a vector you should use [its member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), not passing its address, as you do in your `while` loop.

---